# Redirect all program packets through alerternate port

Tags: c#, vb.net, networking, port, packet-injection

I have an application I need to debug.

The application connects to a server using a specific UDP port, though the application can be configured to join any server with any UDP port.

My goal is to be able to view all incoming data/packets from the server, and be able to accurately send my own packets from my application to the application I want to debug to see and learn from the effects.

My idea was to use some sort of web service to redirect all traffic, sent and received through. With this in mind, I could process the data being received from the server and choose when I want to send my own packets between data being received from the official server.

I am fluent in VB.NET and C#, if anyone has any tips or ideas to help kick-start this project! Thank you to all who helpout! :)

Comment: Way to broad for SO. Look at Fiddler for UI/functionality inspirations and Wireshark for lower level traffic interception

Comment: I've found more about the issue and I know what I am aiming to achieve is UDP packet injection. Any help on that front would be great. Something like Wireshark won't help to send custom packets or edit packets will it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for packet injection if you're interested in this. You can forward all your data through your own proxy/vpn and study the data there.